# Get contents of Meteor template

Tags: templates, meteor

I have the following Meteor template:

```
<template name="homeBoxTpl">
    <div>
        Some content
    </div>
</template>
```

I have an event binding so that when a button on the page is clicked it should get the html contents of the template "homeBoxTpl" - how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is an [event handler](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_events), and like Chase say you can access the content of meteor templates using jquery, but meteor has its own way. In order to get a copy of the html, you can place a wrapper round the content in the template, then do this:

```
Template.homeBoxTpl.events({
  'click #someButton':function(e,t){
       var templateContents = t.$('.wrapperInTemplate').html();  
  }
})
```

Here we are using [Template.$](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_$) wich returns a jQuery object of those same elements.

Take a look into [Template.instances](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_inst) for more information

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify, where is the button? Is it in another template? I assume you only render `homeBoxTpl` once.

In which case the event handler for the template where your button exists will have no reference to another template instance. *There is no global lookup where you can find all rendered instances of a specific `Template`*

You will have to set an unique identifier "id" for it, or some other discerning info such as a class/attribute and find it via old fashioned JS DOM selectors/traversal.

`document.getElementById` is fastest, but if there are multiple instances of that template, `t.firstNode` does give you a good starting point for the DOM traversal.

However making your code dependent on a specific DOM layout is bad practice / too much coupling. Is there any reason why the data underlying that Template's HTML content isn't available somewhere else like a session or collection? It would perhaps be more flexible too to access the data not the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to access what you need. For example, if you have the following template:

```
<template name="homeBoxTpl">
    <div class="content-container">
        Some content
    </div>
    <button id="btn" type="button">Click me</button>
</template>
```

Then use the following javascript:

```
Template.homeBoxTpl.events({
    'click #btn': function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var content = $(".content-container").text();
        console.log(content); //Result is "Some content"
    }
});
```